# I'm looking for a R topic model that I can use to categorize a series of semantics into a discrete list of topics

Tags: r

I have a problem I'm trying to solve. I have a series of data that contains the first 3 columns below, an ID, a sentiment and the comment itself (if one was left). I'd like to be able to identify what topic each comment falls under, so that I can use more advanced methods like regression to determine the things that drive a customer to make a positive or negative review across difference customer segments. The actual data is many thousands of rows, so there's too much data to look through manually. I'm familiar with topic models but is there a method to have a static list of topics (20 or so) and multiple topics per comment?

| ID | Sentiment | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Positive | I loved the food during my stay |
| 2 | Negative | My hotel room was dirty! |
| 3 | Positive | The food and boat were great! |

I'd like the data to appear like this. I'm moderately familiar with R, so I'd prefer to use that but if another language is preferable I'd be okay with that.

| ID | Sentiment | Comment | Food | Room | Transportation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Positive | I loved the food during my stay | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Negative | My hotel room was dirty! | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | Positive | The food and boat were great! | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: I like to use BTM for short text modeling.https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTM/readme/README.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply @stomper. I found the quanteda r package, have you ever used that before? It seems to fit my needs but I'm going to need to figure out how to use it with multiple topics.

Comment: Quanteda is a great package, too. Regardless, it seems like you are going to have to develop your own synonym dictionary to account for how you want to map your topics, i.e, boat = transportation.